# PySide - Click an item inside of a QTreeWidget with QTest

Tags: qt, unit-testing, pyqt, pyside, qtestlib

I'm developing an application with PySide. I'm doing the unit tests before writing any code in the application. I need to select an item inside QTreeWidget so I can use `QTreeWidget.currentItem` to retrieve it and do some stuff with it in order to pass the unit test, I know that I can click widgets using `QTest.mouseClick` however, I'm not sure how to click a item inside a QTreeWidget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted without using `QTest.mouseClick`.

Here is the code:

```
from src import ui
from nose.tools import eq_
from PySide.QtCore import Qt
from PySide.QtTest import QTest

if QtGui.qApp is None:
    QtGui.QApplication([])

appui = ui.Ui()

# ...

def test_movedown_treewidget():
    item = appui.tblURLS.topLevelItem(0)
    appui.tblURLS.setCurrentItem(item)
    QTest.mouseClick(appui.pbtMoveDOWN, Qt.LeftButton)
    # After that click, the connected slot was executed
    # and did something with the current selected widget
    item = appui.tblURLS.topLevelItem(0)

    eq_(item.text(2), u"http://www.amazon.com/example2")


def test_moveup_treewidget():
    item = appui.tblURLS.topLevelItem(1)
    appui.tblURLS.setCurrentItem(item)
    QTest.mouseClick(appui.pbtMoveUP, Qt.LeftButton)
    # After that click, the connected slot was executed
    # and did something with the current selected widget
    item = appui.tblURLS.topLevelItem(0)

    eq_(item.text(2), u"http://www.amazon.com/example1")

# ...
```

Comment: You actually use `Qtest.mouseClick`, so why do you say you don't use it?

Comment: Because clicking on the `QTreeWidget` not necessarily means that I clicked the `QtreeWidgetItem` I want? Or at least that's what I thought...

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to click from the `QModelIndex` and use the `viewport()` method:

```
def clickIndex(tree_view, index):
    model = tree_view.model()
    # If you have some filter proxy/filter, don't forget to map
    index = model.mapFromSource(index)
    # Make sure item is visible
    tree_view.scrollTo(index)
    item_rect = tree_view.visualRect(index)
    QTest.mouseClick(tree_view.viewport(), Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier, item_rect.center())
```